# Use number of distinct values from a column as select criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, select, relational-database

I have the following schema in a mysql database

```
Field       |  Type   |    Null  |  Key  |  Default  |  Extra
------------+---------+----------+-------+-----------+---------
answerId     int(11)      NO       PRI     NULL
answerDate   datetime     YES              NULL
creationDate datetime     YES              NULL
questionId   int(11)      NO       PRI     0
url          text         YES              NULL
description  text         YES              NULL
```

This table stores a relationship of questions and answers, wherein one question is related to one or more answers. What I'd like to do is to select the questions that have more than 5 answers. Is it possible to retrieve that?

Comment: how are you relating a question with its answers in database?

Comment: Hint:  `group by`, `having`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select questionID, count(*) as totalAnswers from qanda
group by questionID
having totalAnswers > 5
```

[Example SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/230ab/6)

Answer (score 2):

Will it work for you ?

```
SELECT questionId
FROM question_answer
GROUP BY questionId
HAVING COUNT(*) >5
```

Side note. Some other attributes ,`url`,`creationDate`, and `description`, don't seem like they describe relationship between question and answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY questionId   
 HAVING count(questionId)> 5
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5268b/2)